# Eclipse conflicting handlers

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, handler, manifest

On developing an eclipse plugin i created a command in the Manifest extensions  with id crtc_v4.session with a default handler crtc_v4.handlers.StartSession , I added a handler in the manifest for this command this handler enables the command according to the variable crtc_v4.sessionvar.

The problem which appears on the console is :

```
!MESSAGE Conflicting handlers for crtc_v4.session:  {crtc_v4.handlers.StartSession@98bc5c} vs {crtc_v4.handlers.StartSession@1265d09}
```

But it doesn't block running the plugin. I'm asking about the solution for this problem, and whether it affects the performance of my plugin in general ?

Edit :

The snippet that define the command :

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
     <toolbar
           id="crtc_v5.crtctoolbar">
        <command
              commandId="crtc_v5.session"
              icon="icons/neutral.png"
              label="Start Session"
              style="push">
        </command>
     </toolbar>
  </menuContribution>
```

The snippet that define the handler :

```
 </extension>
      <command
        defaultHandler="crtc_v5.handlers.StartSession"
        id="crtc_v5.session"
        name="session">
  </command>
 </extension>
```

And here is the enablement against sessionvar :

```
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="crtc_v5.handlers.StartSession"
        commandId="crtc_v5.session">
     <enabledWhen>
        <with
              variable="crtc_v5.sessionvar">
           <equals
                 value="LOGGEDIN">
           </equals>
        </with>
     </enabledWhen>
  </handler>
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the snippets that define the command and the handler?  Also, what does the enablement against sessionvar look like?

Comment: @PaulWebster it is updated now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've defined a default handler in the command and another one in the **org.eclipse.ui.handlers** extension.  If you want to use *enabledWhen*, simply remove the *defaultHandler* attribute (since both instances provide the same handler, **crtc_v5.handlers.StartSession**).

When you want to have different handlers provide the behaviour for your command depending on the application state, you would use *activeWhen* in the **org.eclipse.ui.handlers** definition, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really the problem !